# Splitting an input signal into two separate opamps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal

I am designing a circuit that takes an incoming signal from a preamp and splits the signal into two shaping amplifiers to compare different amplifier settings (via the EL5163 opamps). I was wondering if some sort of buffer should be used to split the input signal. Or will splitting the signal how I have done in the schematic suffice?

EDIT: The input signal is 50 ohm impedance. I am testing RF signals. The signals being tail pulses with a 5 ns rise time.

[image: circuit]

Comment: You do realize that the input capacitors and the potentiometers will form a high pass filter with a cutoff of around 160Hz, right?

Comment: @JRE Yes, I intentionally did this. My reasoning being the input signal will be a tail pulse with a ~5 ns rise time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can usually split an analog signal by just attaching it to the input of two high impedance inputs.  There is often nothing wrong with doing that.

What impedance is high enough depends on how much you are willing to let loading effects change the input signal.  These changes could take the form of either distortion, or simply differences in amplitude.

Right now your input impedance ranges from 500 ohms at DC to 250 ohms at the resonant point of the inductor + plus capacitor (50.3Khz).

If your signal has a source impedance of 50Ω, then you would expect to see loading reduce the signal level between 9.1% to 16.7% depending on frequency.

Easier than adding a buffer might be to just increase the input impedance of the front-end filter components.  The advantage in doing that is that you would not need an extra op-amp, just different component values.

The idea would be to change the component values such that the input signal is not significantly loaded at all, while maintaining the same transfer function.  In that scenario we can basically ignore R1 and the 50Ω source impedance, and the transfer function for one of your front-end filters approximates to...

$$H(s) = \frac{1+s^2L_1C_1+sC_1R_6a}{1+s^2L_1C_1+sC_1R_6}$$

Where R6a is the part of the R6 pot that is between the tap and ground.

As you can see from the equation, if you multiply all the resistors and inductors by a factor X and divide the capacitors by that same factor X, then the transfer function remains unchanged, but the input impedance goes up by a factor of X.  A good starting point would be make X=10 turning the 1K resistors 10K, the 10uH inductor 100uH, and the 1uF capacitor 0.1uF.

Answer (score 1):

what's your input signal's impedance?

That fully defines the answer to this: If it can drive two of your input circuits (R12, C6, L2, R11 || R1, C1, L1, R6) without appearing loaded, you're fine. Otherwise, you need to buffer.

Seeing that R11||R1 form a 500 Ω path to ground, for your source to be loaded less than 1% by that, you need a source impedance <= 5Ω for that alone, even if we ignore the two filters and the potentiometers after that.

Things that have a coax connector very rarely have impedances lower than 20Ω; so, maybe this wasn't a great design to start with!

Comment: The input signal's impedance is 50 ohm, and is input via 50 ohm BNC connection.

Comment: well, is less than 500Ω an acceptable load to that signal? I can't tell you – it depends on how *you* define "acceptable"!

Comment: Would you recommend buffering the input so that the buffer's output impedance is around 500 ohm?

Comment: What's the significance of *R11||R1* - did you intend *R12* there? Close to resonance of C₁L₁(C₆L₂), input impedance should be close to R₁||R₁₂ || R₆||R₁₁). To keep impedance closer to 50 Ω; R₁&R₁₂ should probably be close to 110 Ω.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are testing RF signal. Matching the input impedance to the source wouldn't hurt. An RF splitter can help that.

Comment: Yes I am testing RF signals. I will look into RF splitters.